# Programming a BLE server and a client both in a Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I want to implement a BLE in a Raspberry which sends the result of a sensor apart from it's characteristics and make another Raspberry to obtain that data.

Because the language that offers the possibility to read data from the sensor is written in C, C++ and Python, I have been searching through multiple libraries like [pygattlib](https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/src/default/), [pygatt](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt), [pybluez](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez) and [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) with no result to know how to send data in addition with their characteristics.

Is there any option to reproduce my request?.

I also read about iBeacon and Eddystonne protocol from Apple and Google, however my first point is to comunicate between two Raspberry (server and client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll mark this as an answer because I could make it possible with the libraries written in javascript [noble](https://github.com/noble/noble) and [bleno](https://github.com/noble/bleno)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using rpi you should have Bluez preinstalled. Bluez provides API through D-Bus which you can use to add GAP and GATT functionality. The documentation is in source code of Bluez.

BLE advertising (GAP profile) documentation: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt

BLE data transfer (GATT profile) documentation: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Of course it easier to have an example. They are in Bluez repo too! They are written in Python but it should be easy to translate it to different language because they are using only D-Bus.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-client
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew about Bluez basically because I have been investigating about libraries and the GATT functionality, however I did not try implement it from it.

I also have one question, as the advertising and service are independent until the creation of service_manager, does it means that I should create both managers and just join them in that point?